# What is the definition of "substantial portions of Software" that is used in MIT License?

Tags: intellectual-property, software, open-source-software

Text of MIT License is as follows:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
> a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
> "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
> without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
> distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
> permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
> the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
> included in all copies or **substantial portions of the Software**.

What is the definition of "substantial portions of the Software"?

My use case is that I used existing MIT licensed library written in rather old version of Javascript (copyright year is 2017). I have totally rewritten the library to use Typescript and modern Javascript features. I also improved code by refactoring methods, renamed, applied proper naming convention, applied code design patterns and turning functions to classes, to name few. The overall structure of the library remains similar to old version (main modules are organised the same way), it is doing same things as old one and it remains compatible with old version (the interface remained the same although it is subject to change).

I also added few new features, unit tests and proper bundling configuration. The amount of code has increased significantly compared to original.

In such case do I still need to mention full text of MIT license of the original library in my package?

Should i add the license to every file i made based on old library or keep license text in the root directory?

Where is the boundary between substantial and not substantial portion of the Software.

[update]
Overall I think old library serves rather as an inspiration and source of solutions for some features, but my new code is more than just a 'modification' of the old code.

Comment: Translating a copyrighted work into a new language makes a derivative work.

Comment: it was more than translation, it was full refactor of the code

Comment: If you paraphrase every sentence in a book it's still a derivative work

Comment: Some sentences were removed, some were added, other sentences were changed, then everything was translated to other language. It still tells the same story but in a different way. But the most important question - i it "substantial" or not?

Comment: If you change some sentences you make a derivative work. If you translate a derivative work that is also a derivative work. The only time when there is a question whether it is not a derivative work, is if you change so thoroughly that there is barely any fragment of the original left (not even in paraphrased sentences or translated sentences).

Comment: thanks @user253751 i guess it will be hard to paraphrase 'x = a + b' sentence as they are elementary so i guess it will remain "a derivative work" due to situations like this. Overall, I don't mind putting credit where the credit is due, but stamping each module (a "chapter" of a book)  with the original license where even chapters are completely different now does not feel right.

Comment: and "x = a + b" is not copyrightable. However, a larger collection of sentences including "x = a + b" may be copyrightable. If you wrote a whole chapter from scratch, your chapter might not be derivative but your book still might be because it includes other chapters that are derivative.